# wait for css_parser.getCSSFiles()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to render page when CSS will be loaded. Function `css_parser.getCSSFiles()` reads file asynchronously and sends CSS content to variable `css.cssFile` . How I can force `res.render` to wait for end of file reading?

```
router.get('/main', function(req, res) {

    var directory = '../app/public/stylesheets/',
        file = 'style_720.css';

    css_parser.getCSSFiles(directory,file);
    app.locals.css = css.cssFile;

    res.render('ua', {
        css: app.locals.css,
    });

});

//js module

getCSSFiles: function(directory, fileName) {
    var array = css.cssFile;
       fs.readFile(directory + fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
           if (err) {
               return console.log(err);
           }
           (array.push(data));
       });
}
```

Comment: You can't, unless `getCSSFiles()` tells you when it is done through either returning a promise or accepting a callback.

Comment: So, what is this `css_parser`? What lib are you using, does it have docs? If it's a function you've written yourself, please show it to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change `getCSSFiles()` to accept a callback as an argument and then have it call that callback when it is done and you can then call `res.render()` from inside that callback.  This is the usual way to know when an async operation is done in node.js.

There is no other way to know when it is done.  It has to tell you via a callback or some sort of event notification (one or the other).

If you show us the code for `getCSSFiles()`, we can likely help you more specifically.

What you want to end up with (after modifying `getCSSFiles()`) is something like this:

```
router.get('/main', function(req, res) {

    var directory = '../app/public/stylesheets/',
        file = 'style_720.css';

    css_parser.getCSSFiles(directory,file, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
             res.render('ua', {css: data});
        }
    });
});
```

And, change `getCSSFiles` to this:

```
getCSSFiles: function(directory, fileName, callback) {
       fs.readFile(directory + fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
           if (err) {
               callback(err);
               return console.log(err);
           }
           callback(null, data);
       });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. I've just added getCSSFiles() code.